# C++ Compiler for Win 8 (64 bit)

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm new to programming and so i need a c++ compiler for my windows 8 64 bit os which i can't find. I've tried so many compilers including codeblocks and dev C++.
And the second main problem is that i get error on iostream.
both the compilers says "No such directory" and so tehy give error on "cout<<" and "cin>>".
Kindly tell me such a compiler which is compatible with my laptop and have the lib of iostream.
thank you.

Comment: `Code::Blocks` with a recent MinGW version should have no problem on Windows 8, your problem probably lies in your code or in the project settings.

Comment: They all should? If they were built to work for Windows they should be fine.

Comment: I'm assuming you've considered the obvious: Visual C++?

Answer (score 2):

Try This http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop it works on Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

GCC for Windows 8 is a great start. I used to run it on XP back in the early 2000's.

http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/